Error when trying to configure tp-link bluetooth 5.0 nano usb adapter on debian 5.10.0-33-amd64
I tried to configure the tp-link bluetooth 5.0 nano usb adapter on debian 5.10.0-33-amd64 following the script described at: TP-Link UB500 (rtl8761b) Linux <5.16 Kernel Patch Guide.
In step 4, when using the sudo modprobe -v btusb command, the following error message appears:
insmod /lib/modules/5.10.0-33-amd64/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'btusb': Invalid argument.
I don't know how to solve the problem.  I appreciate your help!
I looked for similar error messages or a solution to the problem, but I didn't find anything relevant.
I would like to know if the problem can be solved or is there another way to configure the tp-link bluetooth nano use adapter in debian 5.10.0-33-amd64.

Is there a reason you can't upgrade to a kernel >5.16?

I actually wanted to understand the problem and resolve it without having to upgrade the kernel. Thanks @eyoung100!

I finally managed to resolve it. I checked the options available at https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/ that were more similar to the output of uname -r, namely 5.10.0-33-amd64. I didn't find any. I ran uname -a getting Linux debian 5.10.0-33-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.226-1 (2024-10-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux. Then check that in the list of https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/ had linux-5.10.226.tar.xz. I redid the step by step in https://github.com/tedboudros/tplink-ub500-linux-patch-guide replace linux-5.11.tar.xz with linux-5.10.226.tar.xz and it worked!
Thanks!
